# Change Chart Axis in Protected Sheet via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, protected

I am struggling to dynamically change the axis of a chart in a protected worksheet.

The code below works on an unprotected sheet.

Once I protect the sheet the code is not unprotecting the sheet and it stops without error at the line `ws.ChartObjects("SUBPlot").Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = upper`.

`MsgBox ws.protectionstatus` will give "true" before and after the unprotect command.

```vb
Function ChangeChartAxisMaxScale(upper)
    Dim pass As String
    pass = "myPassword"

    Dim wasProtected As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If ws.ProtectionMode Then
        ws.Unprotect Password:=pass
        wasProtected = True
    Else
        wasProtected = False
    End If

    ws.ChartObjects("SUBPlot").Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = upper

    If wasProtected Then
        ws.Unprotect Password:=pass, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, DrawingObjects:=True
        ws.EnableOutlining = True
    Else
    End If

End Function
```

I tried to unprotect the entire worksheet using my unprotect routine (which works if called separately).
I tried to call the worksheet directly (via worksheet name) to remove any potential issues with the referencing.

Comment: `ws.ProtectionMode` returns true if it's protected in interface mode only (i.e., it will return false if protected against macros also). I don't think there's a `.ProtectionStatus` property.

Comment: Thank you, I checked with ws.ProtectContents but it doesn't make a difference. The code enters the IF statements as intended, but the issue is that the sheet is never unprotected.  When removing the code manipulating the chart and reprotecting the sheet, the sheet will still be protected, despite the ws.unprotect line firing.

Comment: `ws.Unprotect Password:=pass` should unprotect the sheet. What happens when you step over the code? Is the sheet unprotected then? You've also got a typo when you are reprotecting at the end - it should be `ws.Protect` not `ws.Unprotect`.

Comment: Hi SSlinky, I did try that. When stepping over the code or when commenting out the remainder of the code, the worksheet is not unprotected - and I simply do not know why - which is infuriating. Using the same line in my unprotect routine does work, however. 

Thanks for highlighting the typo.

Comment: Does it work if you enter it manually in the Immediate window? Can also try the macro recorder, record yourself manually unprotecting and then check if executing that code unprotects it. Have you turned off alerts with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and your password is just wrong?